# Get music preview - Google Play Music API

Tags: android, api, google-play, google-music

Is there a way to get preview from songs of Google Play Music? I have checked a couple of unofficial APIs:

[GMUSICAPI](http://unofficial-google-music-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

[Unofficial Google Music API Project](https://github.com/simon-weber/gmusicapi)

I need:

Open Google Play page for buying selected song.

But most importantly:

Get songs preview.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about *Google Play*, but I have worked with the [Spotify API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/) and it allows you to see song stats and preview the song. 
The docs can be a bit confusing so if you have questions let me know. All the best

Comment: Hello Sam. Your comment does not answer the question. You will be able to add comments to questions when you have enough reputation points. Your text would be a good comment but is not suitable as an answer.